# PHP date issue with week monday and saturday date

Tags: php, date

I want to get the start date and end date of a week .
I am using

```
$monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this monday', strtotime($model->date)));
$saturday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this saturday', strtotime($model->date)));
```

when date is 18-09-2017 then monday is 18-09-2017 and saturaday is 23-09-2017.
However, when date is 23-09-2017 then monday is 25-09-2017 and saturday is 23-09-2017.

Why is it so?

How can I adjust the code to give always moday as 18-09-2017 and saturday 23-09-2017 when the date is 18-09-2017 or 23-09-2017.
I want uniformity.

Comment: Add 1 day to your date (`strtotime('23-09-2017 + 1 day')`), and then get `last monday` ...

Comment: check again 18-09-2017 and 25-09-2017 both are monday of September. U are looking in October.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this date-time formatting function , convert it in ISO and get current week days

```
<?php
$dt = "23-09-2017";
function getDay($day,$date)
{
    $days = ['Monday' => 1, 'Tuesday' => 2, 'Wednesday' => 3, 'Thursday' => 4, 'Friday' => 5, 'Saturday' => 6, 'Sunday' => 7];

    $date = new \DateTime($date);
    $date->setISODate((int)$date->format('o'), (int)$date->format('W'), $days[ucfirst($day)]);
    return $date;
}
echo "Monday: ".getDay('Monday',$dt)->format("d-m-Y");

echo "Saturday: ".getDay('Saturday',$dt)->format("d-m-Y");
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/UciDf)

Answer (score 1):

My code is

```
$dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($model->date));
                if($dayofweek == 6)
                {
                    $monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last monday', strtotime($model->date)));
                }
                else
                {
                    $monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this monday', strtotime($model->date)));
                }
                $saturday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this saturday', strtotime($model->date)));
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question and delete this "answer".